# below INSERT INTO SELECT not working with user_id,qty and ord_date,how it can be done?Thanx in advance

Tags: php

```
<?php 
  include("config.php");
  if ($_SESSION['uname']=='' || $_SESSION['uid']=='') {
    header('location:login.php');
  } else { 
     $pid=$_GET['prod_id'];
    $q="INSERT INTO 
      cart_tbl(cat_id,com_id,prod_id,
              user_id,price,qty,ord_date) 
       SELECT cat_id,com_id,
           prod_id,'".$_SESSION['uid']."',
           (prod_price-prod_discount) as price,1,
           date(Y-m-d h:i:s) FROM product_tbl 
              WHERE prod_id='".$pid."'";
    $re=mysql_query($q);
 }
?>
```

I want to insert `user_id=$SESSION['UID'],qty=1` and `ord_date=date(Y-m-d h:i:s)` function and other things from **product_tbl**. but,code above not inserting anything in **cart_tbl**.

Comment: did you get any error??

Comment: sorry,user_id=$_SESSION['uid']

Comment: not getting any error.

Comment: echo your query and execute in your db.. plus check your $pid and $user_id by echo

Comment: you are selecting values from one table and insert in another table, within a single query.. is it possible...??

Comment: @palavesamuthu yes its possible

Comment: so what's not working? please describe your exact problem. Also your title needs improvements.

Comment: just try to print your query before inserting, then u can check is there any problem in the sql statement

Comment: i am php beginner.how to print query before inserting?

Comment: just write echo $q; after line $q="/........";

Comment: Try to find out $_SESSION['uid'] and $pid have some value or not? because your query seems correct . and if no error occure then the problem is only in these two variables. either they are null or they or not created at all.try to use mysqli error reporting technique. it also helps you to find out the exact problem

Comment: i foregate to session_start(); in first line.now i can insert but,date(Y-m-d h:i:s) displaying NULL in column ord_date.any suggetion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query is not correct. As per the query you are inserting values by selecting from a table. In your above written query there couldn't be a field like $_SESSION or date parameter. Insert values by traditional SQL query & from other tables do it as you are doing.

Comment: INSERT INTO cart_tbl(cat_id,com_id,prod_id,user_id,price,qty,ord_date) SELECT cat_id,com_id,prod_id,---'".$_SESSION['uid']."',---(prod_price-prod_discount) as price,--1---,---date(Y-m-d h:i:s)-- FROM product_tbl WHERE prod_id='".$pid."'";    ---- shows to be corrected words

Comment: i foregate to session_start(); on first line.now i can insert.but,date(Y-m-d h:i:s) displaying NULL in column ord_date.any suggeesion?